# SpagoBI : Real time console is not getting refreshed

Tags: fiware, iot, spagobi

I created my template using SpagoBI studio, then I deployed it manually on the SpagoBI server.
It is containing only a the detail pannel and I configured the data set to refresh every 5s

the problem is that the refresh is not working!

I change value on the data base but on the pannel it did not get refresh!

Here is my template

```
{

  "datasets" : [ {

    "id" : "mongoLastValues",

    "label" : "mongoLastValues",

    "refreshTime" : 5,

    "memoryPagination" : true,

    "rowsLimit" : 15

  } ],

  "detailPanel" : {

    "pages" : [ {

      "title" : "Page Title",

      "table" : {

        "dataset" : "mongoLastValues",

        "datasetLabels" : "mongoLastValues",

        "columnId" : "_id",

        "columnConfig" : {

          "_id" : {

            "header" : "_id",

            "type" : "string",

            "headerType" : "static"

          },

          "recvTime" : {

            "header" : "recvTime",

            "type" : "string",

            "headerType" : "static"

          },

          "attrType" : {

            "header" : "attrType",

            "type" : "string",

            "headerType" : "static"

          },

          "attrName" : {

            "header" : "attrName",

            "type" : "string",

            "headerType" : "static"

          },

          "attrValue" : {

            "header" : "attrValue",

            "type" : "string",

            "headerType" : "static"

          }

        },

        "filterBar" : {

          "type" : "custom",

          "refreshDataAfterAction" : false

        }

      }

    } ]

  }

}
```

on my log I found multiple errors:

```
it.eng.spagobi.engines.console.services.ServiceExceptionAction.logError: The error full stack trace is:

it.eng.spagobi.utilities.engines.SpagoBIEngineServiceException: An unpredicted error occurred while executing GET_CONSOLE_DATA_ACTION service.
The root cause of the error is: java.util.ConcurrentModificationException
```

another one:

```
04 sept. 2015 15:11:22,868 ERROR it.eng.spagobi.engines.commonj.services.StartWorkAction.service:98 - could not retrieve user id
```

Any ideas what it might causing that the console is not refreshed and what to do to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

please have a look at:
https://www.spagoworld.org/jforum/posts/list/3761.page

A bug in SpagoBI 5.1 was impeding the console from being refreshed correctly:
https://spagobi.eng.it/jira/browse/SPAGOBI-2191

Regards

Davide